# How does linux implement PROT_NONE mode of mprotect on x64 platform?

Tags: linux, memory-management, x86-64, virtual-memory, page-tables

The method `mprotect` have a PROT_NONE option to disable memory access. It means "The memory cannot be accessed at all"

I wonder how it is implemented on x86/x64 platform.

According to the attributes R/W and XD of page table entry, a page can be set to read only and execution-disable. But how to implement `PROT_NONE` mode so that the memory cannot be accessed at all?

In another words, how to produce a exception when memory is read.

1. Directly to invalid the virtual page to trigger page fault?
2. Using CPL and DPL to trigger privilege violation?
3. Delete the map between virtual memory and physical memory to trigger page fault ?

Is limited by my ability, I can't find the implementation mechanism through source code. It seems like only modify the protection flags of page table entry.

Comment: What do you think the difference between (1) and (3) is?  The page tables are a map from virt->phys, and clearing the "present" bit on a PTE is how you delete the virt->phys mapping that the hardware can read.  Is (3) talking about the kernel's bookkeeping, as well or instead of the hardware page table?  Also not sure what you had in mind for (2); the page-table format (https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging#Page_Directory) doesn't include a 2-bit DPL priv level.  Or do you mean clearing the U/S (user/supervisor) bit in the PTE so it will fault for user-space?  That would work, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that mprotect is called from user space on virtual address regions. When protection is set to PROT_NONE, the _PAGE_PRESENT bit is cleared and the _PAGE_PROTNONE bit is set.  Attempting to access the address will cause a page fault.  [Source](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand006.html)

Comment: So you're saying the answer is (1), clear the "present" bit in the page-table-entry (PTE) and `invlpg`, so it's not valid anymore. https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging#Page_Directory .  But not also (3), because changing the permissions to something else must allow reading the same data again later, not a fresh page, if the original wasn't an untouched anonymous page already.  And no mmap can be allowed to reuse that virtual address, it has to stay reserved.  (That sounds right on both points.)

Comment: Correct.  The mapping can't be deleted, because the underlying page must be freed when the process ends.